# v-for different object properties and accessing array of objects inside it

Tags: vue.js

In my application I am receiving object as below :

```
{
 "data1":[
           {},{}{}
        ],
 "data2":[ {},{},{}....],
 "data3":[ {},{},{}.....]
}
```

If someone can help me on how to use v-for here? I want to loop through "data1", "data2"... using v-for. ( in sinlge v-for precisely )

UPDATE:I would like to have object like this.

```
data :[{
    title :"data1",
    values: [{ } {} {}]
    },
    {
    title :"data1",
    values: [{ } {} {}]
    },
    .....
    ]
```

Comment: You can use `Object.Keys(data)`.

Comment: how can I access element inside it ? could you please give me example, 1st one would give me data 1 and how about second value ? How to loop through that

Comment: @htmldev You can check the [Vue Documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object). What exactly is it that you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```html
<div v-for="(value, propertyName, index) in items"></div>
```

**WARNING**

> When iterating over an object, the order is based on the enumeration order of Object.keys(), which is not guaranteed to be consistent across JavaScript engine implementations.

The above can be found on the [Vue Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object).

Comment: You mean I should use two nested loop here?

Comment: @htmldev,  Yes, you need to use the nested loops

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
<div id="app">
      <h2>Todos:</h2>
        <div v-for="t1 in todos.todos1">
        <label>{{t1.text}}</label>
        </div>
        <div v-for="t2 in todos.todos2">
        <label>{{t2.text}}</label>
        </div>
         <div v-for="t3 in todos.todos3">
        <label>{{t3.text}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  todo:{},
    todos:{todos1: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript 1", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue 1", done: false }
    ],
    todos2: [
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle 2", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome 2", done: true }
    ],
     todos3: [
      { text: "Learn Vue 3", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle 3", done: true },

    ]
    }
  },
  created(){
  this.todo = Object.values(this.todos)
  console.log(this.todo)
  }
})
```

Comment: this may work but I can have n number of properties inside object like todos1 todos2 andand so and also I would like to take property reference as well.